# OOM killer or something else killing my processes

Tags: linux

I have a backup script which I run in bash and after running it for a while it says 'killed'. I can't find anything in the messages log file, so what might it be that's killing my process?

Comment: Could you give additional information, like the backup script, or at least the output trace?

Answer (score 0):

Check `dmesg` output for information about the OOM-killed process.

Comment: so if it is not there, a logged in user must have killed it or..?

Comment: To make this clearer, there is nothing in either dmesg or /var/log/messages about a process being killed.